# Navigation toggle icon for phone/email issue

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to get my navigation using elementor to show for example - a phone icon and a telephone number,

I have got this on desktop but I would like just the icon to show on mobile - is this possible at all?

I can't find an example using blocks or other ready-made examples

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

elementor have builtin function for this already. First chose the element you want to hide, then in the advanced tab find responsive section and turn on "Hide on desktop" option. Example in the picture below:

[image]